# How does a Cavalier's Immune to Fear ability work in First Edition D&D?

Tags: adnd-1e

In First Edition D&D, Unearthed Arcana 1985 made the Paladin into a subclass of a new class called the Cavalier.

What creatures is "Immune to Fear" effective against and how does it work?

Comment: -1 You need to be more specific, mate. What edition? What aspects of demons are you specifically wondering about? Complete sentences also help, but external editing can fix that.

Comment: Okay, looking through your comments from your previous question, I *think* this is what you're asking.

Comment: +1 @Brian, with your editing applied the question became a good one.

Answer (score 10):

**The Cavalier is immune to anything fear based.**

The Unearthed Arcana states on p15

> A cavalier makes all saving throws as a fighter.  Such characters are, however, immune to fear (magical or otherwise) of any sort.

The immunity to magical fear is the key.  At a brief glance through the books, all items in the DMG (including artifacts) that cause fear use the mechanics of the spell Cause Fear which would trigger the immunity.

- Monsters cause fear as the Fear Wand (Beholder, demons, devils).
- The Dragon aura is noted as a fear effect so Cavaliers should be immune to it as well.
- A cavalier of under 5th level would not have to run in fear from a lich.  (Although it might be a good idea anyways!)

Comment: +1 especially that last bit of advice--run away from the lich is one of my favorite "powers" from First Edition.